# Плохое качество скриншотов в Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Всем привет.

В Google Play после публикации качество скриншотов становится просто ужасным. Пробовал сохранять в PNG и JPG, перед загрузкой сжимал вес изображений.
Смотрю на скрины через сайт - все окей. Через приложение с телефона (с трех проверял) - качество можете увидеть на приложенных скриншотах.

Уже видел много похожих вопросов, но нет четкого ответа. Кто с таким сталкивался уже? Или даже если не сталкивались, напишите, пожалуйста, максимально подробно как вы создаете скриншоты (в каком разрешении, формате, сжимаете ли размер, сколько весят ваши файлы, может какие-то настройки в фотошопе нужны). Очень важно поправить эту проблему, прошу вашей помощи.

Пример:
[image: Пример]

Ссылка на файлы, которые загружаю в Google Play - https://dropmefiles.com/bVXJl